# Adding support for video or slideshow of images

Tags: feature-request, videos

Up until this point, most of the proposals have been about book and/or practical knowledge, both of which can be easily expressed using words but Sports/Recreation proposals break that mold because they require kinesthetic learning (which is very hard to convey with just words).

**Simple Example:**

Hitting a tennis ball with an overhand strike requires the player to position the racquet in a specific way to hit the ball. A picture may be enough to demonstrate this but a series of progressive pictures and/or a video demonstration would be better.

**Complicated Example:**

On TV snowboarders who do tricks off of big jumps look as though they do it all in one single fluid movement but, in reality, there are many distinct steps to doing even the simplest tricks off of a jump. For instance, to throw a backside 360 off of a kicker (massive tabletop jump) you need to approach the jump on the heelside edge slightly to the right of your launch point for balance, switch to your toeside edge at the layup point as the edge you take off from, straighten out your lead up to the jump so you land straight, torque your body in the opposite direction of the spin to build up counter momentum leading in to the lip, bend your knees in preparation to pop off of the lip, torque your body in the direction of the spin as you approach the lip, spot the landing when you reach 270 degrees through the spin, absorb the landing.

Setup to do the trick is to practice jumping and torquing your whole body 360 degrees without a board while keeping your body straight. Practice with your board by spring off of your toeside edge to get the feel of launching and landing the spin without losing your balance (spinning off axis in the air because of loss of balance can lead to a really painful if not injuring fall, I know...). Then take a few runs off the jump doing straight airs (jumping straight with no tricks) to gauge the speed you need to approach the jump without hitting the knuckle (landing too short and hitting the flat or bump before the downslope on the landing) or landing flat (landing too long and missing the downslope effectively falling farther and landing on flat ground).

The hardest part about all this is, if you choke up and forget one step it can be a really painful experience. You'll hear a lot from sports people that you should visualize what you intend to do before you do it. Sit and imagine yourself going through the steps and try to feel the movement.

I have literally spent hours when I couldn't sleep doing mental visualizations of tricks I was working on and it works but, as you could probably tell, it's very difficult to visualize the movement by reading the text description. Don't know what I mean, [watch the video that the above description is based on](http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-do-the-Backside-360-Snowboard-Trick-79554604).

---

The same can pretty much apply to anything that requires precise physical movement (Ex, dance, martial arts, etc...).

Is this a feature that could be made available in the future? Or is it completely outside the scope of Stack Exchange site functionality?

Comment: +1 for presenting the question in a lot better way than I did,ended up being voted -8([this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89664/extending-the-capabilities-of-stack-overflow-by-adding-video-tutorials)

Answer (score 4):

We are potentially enabling this on a site-by-site basis, as needed. For example, gaming.se has youtube support enabled.

Make the case for it on your site's meta, as it is a site specific decision.

Comment: Well we definitely need it here, for unicorns and ponies and stuff like that. Animated free hand circles too...